# Add $_GET variable inside include link

Tags: php, get

How can add the content of a $_GET variable inside my include link

```
<?php $variable = $_GET['variable']; ?>
```

where my variable is placed here:

```
<?php
    include 'includes/link_(variable placed here).php';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use [concatenation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php):

```
include 'includes/link_'.$variable.'.php';
```

FYI, this is a [security risk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.filesystem.php). You should sanitize and validate that value before you use it.

Comment: why is that a security risk??

Comment: Someone can pass an arbitrary file path as a variable which can cause your script to potentially download malicious code.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use it as the string it is:

```
include 'includes/link_'.$variable;
```

Be careful with trying to use includes on code that is based on user input. Trouble trouble, boil and bubble!

Answer (score 0):

It can be concatenated like any other string:

```
include 'includes/link_' .$variable;
```

However, when using user input in includes, **you must** validate and verify the data to ensure you don't leave yourself open to a [Local File Inclusion vulnerability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_inclusion_vulnerability).

Answer (score 0):

This might help:

```
<?php

/* This example assumes that www.example.com is configured to parse .php
* files and not .txt files. Also, 'Works' here means that the variables
* $foo and $bar are available within the included file. */

// Won't work; file.txt wasn't handled by www.example.com as PHP
include 'http://www.example.com/file.txt?foo=1&bar=2';

// Won't work; looks for a file named 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2' on the
// local filesystem.
include 'file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

// Works.
include 'http://www.example.com/file.php?foo=1&bar=2';

$foo = 1;
$bar = 2;
include 'file.txt';  // Works.
include 'file.php';  // Works.

?>
```

Source: [include](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)